# Set [Automatically wrap text] in Java mail

Tags: java, email

i have an account register function, after user inputted personal data, an confirm email will be sent to that customer with a generated link. The problem is that: because the link is too long, it is broken into two lines (The second line is from character 76) and the second line does not belong the the first line (User cannot click on the whole link). I think this problem may come from the word wrap or something like that

In Outlook Express, under menu->Tools->Options->Send->HTML setting, we can set number of characters that the email content should be wrapped in each line by changing the value. Is there any way to set this function using core Java Mail?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Word wrapping is done by the viewer (i.e. Outlook Express) not when sending email. I would guess that you are sending plain text emails and relying on the viewers to try and identify that it contains links. Try sending HTML mail and using ''

Answer (score 0):

No, JavaMail is a library allowing you to send/receive email through Java. It is not an application like Outlook/Outlook Express or Thunderbird for that matter.

That said, you can write code that does the formatting before it invokes JavaMail to send the email out.

Answer (score 0):

First, you can't set a setting in java mail to change a client's formatting.

Second, while my solution might not be the best answer to the question. It should help with the problem you are having.

Before adding your link into the body of the mail make sure you;

1. Put the link on a new line. "\n" ;)
2. Make a little method using URL shortening API like [bitlyj](http://code.google.com/p/bitlyj/) for bit.ly to shorten the URL. Add the shortened link and walla!

> ```
> msg.setContent("This is an example of adding a shortened URL\n" 
> + shortLink("http://www.longlink.com") 
> + "\n", "text/plain");
> ```

---

> ```
> public String shortLink(String link) {
>       Url url = as("Username", "APIKey").call(shorten(link));
>       return url.getShortUrl();
> }
> ```

Using this approach you shouldn't have any issues with word wrap stuff.

Comment: Thank you for your answer but i cannot apply this method into my project as setting problem. anyway i really appreciated your help

Comment: Cool, no worries. I actually learnt something about java mail authentication from writing and testing my answer so thank you for posting the question.